# How to Change the Mouse Pointer on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse

Or make a program that will do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open System Preference, navigate to Universal Access, click Mouse & Trackpad, change "Cursor Size" to as large as you like.

Comment: the resulting cursor looks ugly :(

Comment: Is there an app or other method to change the mouse pointer entirely - not just the size?